# "functions have a __get__() method so that they can be converted to a method when accessed as attributes."

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to  Python's  [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#id9)

> functions have a `__get__()` method so that **they** can be converted to **a method** when accessed as attributes.

does

> The non-data descriptor transforms an **`obj.f(*args)`** call into **`f(obj,*args)`**. Calling **`klass.f(*args)`** becomes **`f(*args)`**.

mean that

- `obj.f(*args)` is converted to `f(obj,*args)`, and `klass.f(*args)` to `f(*args)`?
- `obj.f(*args)` and `klass.f(*args)` are function calls, and `f(obj,*args)` and `f(*args)` method calls? I feel the opposites are true: `obj.f(*args)` and `klass.f(*args)` are method calls, and `f(obj,*args)` and `f(*args)`  function calls.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a link to where you are quoting this from? It’s difficult to see what it’s referring to without context.

Comment: All righty. Let me give you the link.

Answer (score 4):

> `obj.f(*args)` is converted to `f(obj,*args)`, and `klass.f(*args)` to `f(*args`)?

Yes.  In Python 3, though, `klass.f(*args)`, is not "converted" because unbound methods no longer exists, so `klass.f` is just plain `f`.

> `obj.f(*args)` and `klass.f(*args)` are function calls, and `f(obj,*args)` and `f(*args)` method calls?

No.  `f` is a function.  When that function is accessed as an attribute of an instance, as in `obj.f`, the result is a method object.  So `obj.f(*args)` is a call on the method object.  The method object underlyingly converts that into the function call `f(obj, *args)`, as described above.  Also, as described above, `klass.f` in Python 3 is just a plain function, so both `klass.f(*args)` and `f(*args)` are equivalent.

I find it is best not to get too hung up on the distinction between "methods" and "functions" in Python.  In Python, unlike some other languages, you can make many kinds of objects callable (by defining a `__call__` method).  Because of this, when you see `some_obj()`, it doesn't mean `some_obj` must be either a function or a method --- it could be some other callable object --- and so the difference between those two is not so crucial.  Rather, you just want to think about what callable behavior an object defines.  Ultimately all these calls turn into function calls, and "method" is just a name for one particular kind of common callable object, whose callable behavior is that it inserts the `self` argument before calling the underlying function, as described above.

Comment: Thanks. Does "functions have a `__get__()` method so that they can be converted to a method when accessed as attributes" mean that functions are converted to methods? Is it contrary to  what you said that method calls are converted to function calls?

Comment: @Tim: In a sense both happen.  When you access `obj.f`, you get a method object which is "built" from the original function.  When you call that method object, it internally calls the underlying function.  Method objects are wrappers, where the function itself is "converted" into a method, and then calls to the method are "converted" back into calls to the function.  ("Convert" may be a slightly misleading term here; it is more like translation, as the original function is not changed in any way; you just get a new object that wraps the original function.)

Comment: Does "access" not include "call"?

Comment: @Tim:  No, they are separate.  "Accessing as an attribute" means just doing `obj.f`.  Calling it is doing `obj.f()` (or `obj.f(some, arguments)`).  You can for instance do `x = obj.f`, accessing the method and storing it, and then later call it with `x()`.